# Запуск ASp. net + web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Написал в студию (MS VS 2012) ASP .net mvc веб-приложение и сервис для него, как запустить все это на IIS?

Comment: Запустить приложение получилось, но получаю сообщение что служба не найдена, как я понял надо как-то сконфигурировать WEB.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Deploying ASP.NET Websites on IIS 7.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0)

Comment: Проблема остаеться прежней Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение 127.0.0.1:64983

Comment: Данный порт попахивает дев-сервером, а не ИИСом. В данном ответе довольно подробное описание - что сделали и что не получилось?

Comment: Сделал publish сервера и сервиса в одну папку, затем запустил IIS, с указанием на эту папку (сама страница видна, но она не видит сервис)

Comment: Под сервисом понимается отдельный под-проект на ВЦФ ? Или в рамках одного сайта у вас есть асмх сервис? Если ВЦФ, то с ним может быть масса ньюансов и настроек. Мало информации, чтобы вам помочь.

Comment: Как раз таки WCF

Comment: ВЦФ сервис ВНУТРИ вебного проекта? То есть ваш вебный проект хостит данный сервис? Как вы его проверяете? Вы уверены, что ваш сервис вообще рабочий? Как минимум стоило бы выложить ваш конфиг файл (соответствующие секции из него)

Answer (score 0):

Плюнул я на web service, написал DLL вместо веб сервиса и никаких проблем с развертыванием.